# The connection has been reset

Tags: mamp

I am using Mamp for execute web site... I have several projects there and everything is fine.
Today hay export other project than I download from FTP and I can´t see the index.php

When I put the router in the browser I obtain

```
The connection has been reset
```

I have all permission on the file of the project ... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a permanent solution (maybe a poor one), but I also encounter this problem sometime. Restarting MAMP might help.